# Jquery Sortable and droppable with their own element

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

**HTML A**

```
<div class="template_menu1 droppable1 id="main_list1">

   <div class="draggable" id="superwear2_current">
       <span style="float:left" class="listing">
           <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
       </span>
   </div>

   <div class="draggable" id="superwear3_current">
      <span style="float:left" class="listing">
          <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
      </span>
   </div>       

</div>
```

**HTML B**

```
<div class="template_menu droppable" id="main_list">
   <div class="draggable" id="banner">
      <span style="float:left" class="listing">
          <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
      </span>
   </div>

   <div class="draggable" id="multitab">
      <span style="float:left" class="listing">
        <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**HTML C**

```
<div class="site_template droppable droppable1" id="column_left">Left Column</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$( ".droppable,.droppable1" ).sortable({
    connectWith: '.droppable,.droppable1',
    revert: 200,
    tolerance:'pointer',
    start: function(){

    },
    stop: function(event,ui){

    },
    zIndex: 10
}).droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {



     }
});
```

**QUESTION:**
I tried to created 3 box which is **A, B, C** with able to **sortable** and **droppable**. Above code is able to *drag* and *drop* each other. For example, Element inside **A** are able to drag to **A** and **B**,Element inside **B** are able to drag to **A** and **C** and Element inside **C** are able to drag to **A** and **B**.

Furthermore,*this is not what I want, I want it will be Element inside **A** only able to drag to Element C and also can drag back to Element **A**, then Element inside **B** only able to drag to Element **C** and also can drag back to Element **A***

Please advise, really no idea about that :(

**Working Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/PWh2L/72/

Comment: If i'm not wrong, summarize your requirement, drag and drop; A ->C, C->A and B->C, C->B. right?

Comment: yaya, this is what I want :(

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect the sortables in the right order: A with C, B with C and C with A.

See updated jsfiddle:

```
added ids for the divs
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PWh2L/74/

Updated it again, hope you understand the logis behind it as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/PWh2L/85/

Comment: Almost work, but I found that one bug, when I drag  **section B** element to **section C** , then I was unable to drag back to **section B**, only can drag to **section A**. Can you help me to check :( ?

Comment: updated the fiddle, you can play with the connections to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1,#div2,#div3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
p{float:left; width:50px; height:20px;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    if(ev.target.id == "div3")
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    else if(data.substring(0,4) == ev.target.id)
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<p>A</p>
    <p id="div1Text1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Text11</p>
    <p id="div1Text2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Text12</p>
    <p id="div1Text3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Text13</p>
</div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<p>B</p>
    <p id="div2Text1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Text21</p>
    <p id="div2Text2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Text22</p>
    <p id="div2Text3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Text23</p>
</div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<p>C</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

by using [`accept`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept) option :

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".droppable").droppable({
            greedy : true,
            // accept from both draggable area 1 and draggable area 2
            accept : '#draggable1 .listing1, #draggable2 .listing2',
        });

        $("#draggable2").droppable({
            greedy : true,
            // accept only from itself
            accept : '#draggable2 .listing2',
        });

        $("#draggable1").droppable({
            greedy : true,
            // accept only from itself
            accept : '#draggable1 .listing1',
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

live demo : https://jsfiddle.net/q4dbu9fh/